# Is simplification of $(t^2)(t^2-1^2)(t^2-2^2)\ldots(t^2-a^2) \bmod (2t-1)$ possible?

Tags: number-theory

Is it possible to further simplify or reduce the following equations,

$$(t^2)(t^2-1^2)(t^2-2^2)(t^2-3^2)\ldots(t^2-a^2) \bmod (2t-1)$$
Or
$$(t-a) \ldots (t-3)(t-2)(t-1)(t^2)(t+1)(t+2)(t+3) \ldots (t+a) \bmod (2t-1)$$

assuming $a,t \in \mathbb Z_+$ and $a < t-1$

Comment: Is the mod in $\mathbb Q[t]$ or $\mathbb Z[t]$?

Comment: I thought $t$ is an integer!

Comment: t is an integer, apologies for missing that in the question. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $a,t \in \mathbb Z_+$ and $1\le a \le t-1$ inclusive, then the term $t^2-(t-1)^2=2t-1\equiv 0 \bmod (2t-1)$, and the product $\equiv 0 \bmod (2t-1)$

Comment: Any simplification for $a < t-1$? I have edited the question to reflect that bound. Brilliant understanding of the problem on your part though...

Comment: I doubt there is any simple systematic analysis to be had for $a<t-1$. Consider if $2t-1$ is prime: then the product is $t$ times a series of consecutive numbers smaller than a prime. That cannot be $\equiv 0$, but it is not readily apparent what it would be equivalent to. If $2t-1$ is composite, then for some such products, one or more of the factors of $2t-1$ might or might not occur in the series of consecutive numbers, depending on how long that series is; it could have as few as $3$ factors, or other odd numbers, depending on the arbitrary choice of $a$.